# Python divmod for every value in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, divmod

I've got a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
   P-101  P-103  P-104  P-107  P-114  P-120
P   2415   2535   3345   5650   2805   6210
S      0     45   3105   1165      0      0
D      0    690    690    570    255    830
```

I want to apply a `divmod(value, 60)` to each cell, then format the result as `[quotient]h[remainder]m`, like this: `5h30m`

I've tried:

```
df.values.apply(lambda x: divmod(x,60))
```

But that throws out an `AttributeError`

How can I apply `divmod` to every value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `applymap`, which applies the function element-wise rather than row- or column-wise in the case of `apply`:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: divmod(x,60))
```

Comment: I had actually just found it myself, but thank you so much for helping. +1.